# Neovim colorscheme does not look right when using nvim inside tmux

Tags: vim, command-line, command-line-interface, tmux, neovim

I'm trying to use vim-material theme from https://github.com/kaicataldo/material.vim

**Below is what happens when i run neovim in tmux**
[image: neovim in tmux]

**Below is what it should look like**
[image: neovim not in tmux]

**What i've tried so far:**

in my .tmux.conf
I tried both

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

and

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

I also tried

```
TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux
```

I am able to echo $TERM with proper results here. but i've also tried setting them manually with `export TERM=xterm-256color` or `export TERM=screen-256color` before i open nvim

This is what I have in my init.vim

```
let g:material_theme_style = 'ocean'
colorscheme material
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
set termguicolors
```

i've tried setting and unsetting these.
unsetting termguicolors was the worst, the theme just didnt work and it gave me default vim look

I also run tmux as `tmux -2` i should also mention i kill tmux sessions after changing anything in my tmux.conf to make sure it reflects

the versions of related apps and os

```
nvim v0.4.3
tmux 3.0a
iTerm2 3.3.9
macOS mojave 10.14.6
```

EDIT:

I've since tried clearing all tmux plugins and nvim plugins only leaving the default-terminal in my tmux config

Here's what's left on my init.vim file

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')

Plug 'kaicataldo/material.vim'
call plug#end()

set termguicolors
let g:material_theme_style = 'default'
colorscheme material
```

I also tried downloading an older version of tmux. 2.5, still no luck.

I deleted all my tmux plugins and nvim plugins and reinstalled material.vim so i'm sure nothing is conflicting in the plugins somehow

Answer (score 34, accepted):

FOUND THE SOLUTION . this article helped me:
https://www.cyfyifanchen.com/blog/neovim-true-color

```
set-default colorset-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
```

Comment: In tmux, set-default is an unknown command.

Comment: now it's instead: set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"

Comment: omg thx so much!

Comment: `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`

Comment: set `xterm-256color` to the value of `$TERM` when not in tmux if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 8):

I ran `h: checkhealth` in neovim and I was only getting an error message when I was using neovim inside a tmux session. The checkhealth message provided the only solution that worked for me.

This is what it said:

```
  - WARNING: Neither Tc nor RGB capability set. True colors are disabled. |'termguicolors'| won't work properly.
    - ADVICE:
      - Put this in your ~/.tmux.conf and replace XXX by your $TERM outside of tmux:
          set-option -sa terminal-overrides ',XXX:RGB'
      - For older tmux versions use this instead:
          set-option -ga terminal-overrides ',XXX:Tc'
```

Answer (score 8):

For me it worked like this, writing in `.tmux.config`

```
set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just change the `TERM` environment variable in your shell config file, in my case `.zshrc`, i.e:

```
# Path Variables
export TERM='xterm-256color'
export EDITOR='nvim'
export VISUAL='nvim'
```

Reload your terminal and reload tmux or kill tmux-server and check:

```
> echo $TERM
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me from here.

Answer (score 4):

`set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"` in `.tmux.conf` and `alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"` in `.bashrc` worked for me in windows WSL2 using windows terminal. now I can use vim within tmux :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, setting the following in my `~/.bashrc` helped:

```
export TERM='xterm-direct'
```

Of course, once you update your `.bashrc`, exit tmux and end all the tmux servers, then `source ~/.bashrc`, then start tmux again.

No need to add anything else in my `~/.tmux.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Since i use an old version of TMUX (that doesnt support all colors) this was my solution:

```
  -- Set colorscheme              
  vim.o.termguicolors = false               
  vim.cmd [[colorscheme default]]
```